# Grails request.withFormat and dynamically scaffolded views not working

Tags: grails

I've got a Grails app configured to dynamically scaffold all views.  In my controllers I want to handle multiple request and response content types - particularly html and json:

```
request.withFormat {
    html { 
        // do something 
    }
    json { 
        // do something else 
    }
}
```

Looking at the 2.2.x documentation I see that there is request.withFormat which can be used to react to the request CONTENT_TYPE.  For JSON requests coming from my custom client app this works without issue but when servicing requests from the dynamically scaffolded views, none of the methods defined in my request.withFormat are matched and executed.

Is there something special I need to do to make the dynamically scaffolded views set the request content type correctly?

Comment: withFormat works based on the requested format - ie Accept header (if you have turned it on, format=... query param etc). request.withFormat is for the Content-Type of the body

Answer (score 0):

enabel the following: in config.groovy

```
grails.mime.use.accept.header = true
```

See bottom of:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html

Comment: uh, yes it does ... from Grails doc: Grails ignores the HTTP Accept header unless you add a grails.mime.use.accept.header = true setting to your Config.groovy file. In other words, withFormat() will be completely unaffected by the Accept header without that setting.

Comment: sorry I misclicked when reviewing posts.

Comment: I've added this config but my accept header is still being ignored. any ideas?

Comment: request.WithFormat is not related to Access headers. Access headers related only with WithFormat (bit not request.WithFormat)